# Is it possible to make instant coffee of varying roasts?

Tags: roasting, instant

I've never seen instant coffees being sold consisting of varying roasts (i.e. light/mild, medium, dark etc.) does such a thing exist? Or is there a reason why they haven't been tried?

Comment: Just stumbled across this. https://www.suddencoffee.com/ It's not a different roast type but it is an instant specialty coffee. Thought it might be helpful to you.

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason why instant coffee couldn't be roasted differently. It's made from real coffee beans after they have been roasted and ground. Instant coffee is just [dehydrated coffee](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/entry/what-is-instant-coffee_us_57bda1ebe4b00d9c3a1afc74) basically.

I think the reason you have never seen different roasts types is because instant coffee is made more for convenience. It's supposed to be quick, easy coffee. [It's made for the "Amateur coffee drinker"](https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/wonk/wp/2014/07/14/almost-half-of-the-world-actually-prefers-instant-coffee/?utm_term=.1d91b6639ba4)(If there is such a thing). For that reason those purchasing the coffee probably don't care much about how it will taste and therefor care very little about the roast type.

Comment: Wow! Very interesting. I wonder if it would be marketable.

Comment: Instant coffee is **dehydrated coffee**, not **dehydrated coffee grounds** (which are already *quite* well dehydrated as they come out of the roaster) no matter what you read from huffpost, not exactly a quality source of facts.

Comment: Valid point, huffpost is not exactly a quality source. Either way the answer to his question remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

Of Course one can. Instant coffee is made by a process called freeze drying or lyophilizing ground coffee beans but since it is supposed to be quick and instant I think people who manufacture these do not bother with marketing the type of roast on the bottle. It is simply a matter of branding really.... for a person who does not care much other than the time and effort to make coffee surely wouldn't bother with the type of roast.

Although a company called BRU did manufacture instant coffee's from different regions around the world specifying strengths and aromas. you might wanna take a look at that. It's called 'Bru Exotica'